# JS function in Brython

Tags: javascript, python, function, brython

I wrote some simple js functions in objects.js file, but I can't reach them in python script

When i paste all code from file to index.html, everything works fine

How to execute functions from file objects.js ?

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="doc/doc_brython.css">
</head>

<body onload="brython({debug:1, cache:'none'})">
<canvas id="spriteCanvas" width="640" height="480" style="border:1px     solid #FF8844"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript" src="objects.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/brython.js"></script>

<script type="text/python">
from browser import window
from browser import document as doc
pyjs=window

pyjs.create("instance",256,128);
pyjs.create("instance",256,256);
pyjs.create("player",128,256);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

objects.js:

```
console.log("Brytan v0.1");

var canvas= document.getElementById("spriteCanvas");

function create(inst)
{instances.push(inst); instances[instances.length-1].id=instances.length; return instances[instances.length-1];}    

function instance(x,y)
{
canvas = document.getElementById("spriteCanvas");
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
this.context=context;
this.canv=canvas
this.img = new Image();
this.imagePath = "";

this.id=0;
this.x=x;
this.y=y;
this.w=32;
this.h=32;

this.update=function()
{   
    /// Mozna nadpisac ta funkcje w innych obiektach
}
this.draw=function()
{
    this.img.onload = drawImage(
    this.context, this.img, 
    this.x, this.y,
    this.w, this.h
    );
}

this.destroy= function() // Swiec GC nad jego dusza
{instances[this.id-1]=0;}

this.img.src="./pieniazek.png";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The code fails because the variable `instances` is not declared in objects.js.

It's not obvious what you want to do with

`pyjs.create("instance",256,128)`

In objects.js, `create` only takes one argument. If you want to pass the object created by the constructor `instance` in objects.js, you can use this syntax in Brython code :

`pyjs.create(pyjs.instance.new(256, 128));`

Answer (score 0):

Function "create" created in a local js-scope. Try to

```
window.create = create
```

after function definition and it will be available through

```
pyjs.create
```